# Unity interface issues with AMD Radeon 6450

Tags: unity, graphics, radeon, ati

Is the AMD Radeon 6450 blacklisted for 11.04? I get an error message saying my hardware is not compatible for Unity. I have an i5-processor, DL-67 Intel Motherboard,4 GB RAM, and 1 GB Radeon 6450 Graphics...
(New to Linux!)

Comment: if you're using nvidia or ati you might have to install binary drivers from alternate then install the desktop package

Comment: You should say which version of Ubuntu you are using. If you're on 11.04, then you should consider upgrading. The radeon drivers have improved. I find it strange that your card should be blacklisted, though. I use an HD5850, and it works well out of the box. My understanding is that AMD is focusing on newer cards, so if anything, I would guess your card was better supported than mine.

Answer (score 1):

I am using ATI HD4870 and while I was using Ubuntu 11.04, I also had your issue. But installing the official driver from AMD site:

[here](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.42&lang=English)

is the link to the 64bit driver of your card. Make sure you have Ubuntu 11.04 64bit, otherwise download the 32bit version.
Read the release note there for useful info. After download run the following command in the terminal, from your download location:

```
 sudo sh ./ati-driver-installer-x86.x86_64.run
```

Follow the instruction and you should be fine. 
I recommend you keep the driver on your disk, because every kernel update, or when you see that the shell does not start up properly after a reboot, you need to reboot into low graphics and re-run the above command.

You can also force the driver to be installed:

```
sudo sh ./ati-driverinstaller-x86.x86_64.run --force
```

For uninstall:

```
sudo aticonfig --uninstall
```

Hope it helps